# Image Straightening in Android Sample

Tags: android, image-rotation

I want to implement **Straightening** so that a user can rotate an image.  Could someone provide a code snippet or an example of image Straightening?  I have tried to find an example but have failed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This post can save your time! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18865837/image-straightening-in-android

Comment: thanks for reply @HarshDattani. i seen that link but i am failed to convert it as sample

Comment: If you are in search of sample, then probably this could help you. 
http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/07/rotate-bitmap-image-using-matrix.html

Comment: A library to save your time. https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview

Comment: @HarshDattani the link is for rotating here i need sample for straighten an image like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18865837/image-straightening-in-android

Comment: @HarshDattani i tried github link above you mentioned its not related this post..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Here is a sample implementation:

**HomeActivity.java**

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    private ImageView mImageView;
    private Matrix mMatrix;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        // load bitmap from resource
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sample2);

        // calculate suitable width / height
        int WIDTH = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        int HEIGHT = (int)((image.getHeight() / (image.getWidth() * 1.0f)) * WIDTH);

        // scale image to be visible on screen
        image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, WIDTH, HEIGHT, false);

        // configure image view accordingly
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        mImageView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(image);

        SeekBar seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.rotate_bar);
        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        float angle = (progress - 45);
        float width = mImageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
        float height = mImageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();

        if (width > height) {
            width = mImageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
            height = mImageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
        }

        float a = (float) Math.atan(height/width);

        // the length from the center to the corner of the green
        float len1 = (width / 2) / (float) Math.cos(a - Math.abs(Math.toRadians(angle)));
        // the length from the center to the corner of the black
        float len2 = (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(width/2,2) + Math.pow(height/2,2));
        // compute the scaling factor
        float scale = len2 / len1;

        Matrix matrix = mImageView.getImageMatrix();
        if (mMatrix == null) {
            mMatrix = new Matrix(matrix);
        }
        matrix = new Matrix(mMatrix);

        float newX = (mImageView.getWidth() / 2) * (1 - scale);
        float newY = (mImageView.getHeight() / 2) * (1 - scale);
        matrix.postScale(scale, scale);
        matrix.postTranslate(newX, newY);
        matrix.postRotate(angle, mImageView.getWidth() / 2, mImageView.getHeight() / 2);
        mImageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }
}
```

**activity_home.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/rotate_bar"
        android:max="90"
        android:progress="45"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Note**: You will need a `drawable` named `sample2` for the above code to work.

Comment: is it possible to apply straighten 360 degrees?

Comment: If you want 360 degree, you should go for rotation. Straightening generally means slight (zoom + rotate right) / (zoom + rotate left). The above equations for straightening do not work for more than +90/-90 degrees.

Comment: ok.. thanks for reply... i have one more issue if image height >= width then its  working fine otherwise image position was changing...

Comment: My mistake. If width is bigger, swap it with height. See updated answer. Thanks :)

Comment: i have an another issue after straightening when i drag the image original image dragging not resulted image do you have any idea?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea.

Comment: its ok.. thanks for reply... is there any alternative?